# JavaScript functions is throwing Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

I have a web page. In my web page I'm referencing some JavaScript I've written in a file called "spacer.js". spacer.js is more complicated, but the general setup is like this:

```
function spacer() {
  // do stuff
  console.log(spacer.options);
}

spacer.initialize = function(options) {
  spacer.options = options;
};
```

Then, in my web page, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./spacer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  spacer.initialize({ id:1 });
  window.onresize = spacer();
</script>
```

When I load my web page, I get an error that says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: spacer.initialize is not a function.
```

I don't understand. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: I don't understand how you can get a `TypeError`, before even having a `SyntaxError`

Comment: @Teemu & War10ck: Gah, right you are. It would need a newline after the ) so ASI would kick in.

Comment: *"Uncaught TypeError: spacer.initialize is not a function."* Not with the updated question's code you don't. But the `window.onresize = spacer();` assigns `undefined` to `onresize`, as `spacer` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Shouldn't `src="./spacer.js"` be `src="spacer.js"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an aside it looks like you're trying to do one of two things and sitting uncomfortably in the middle. I'd personally go for 1) in this instance, but probably best to stick with one or the other.

1) Creating an *object* with methods

```
var spacer = {};

spacer.initialize = function (options) {
    this.options = options;
}

spacer.getOptions = function () {
    return this.options;
}

spacer.initialize({ name: 'spacer' });
spacer.getOptions(); // { name: spacer });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cq7Lva1m/)

2) Using a constructor *function* to build an space object instance:

```
function Spacer() {}

Spacer.prototype.initialize = function (options) {
  this.options = options;
  return this;
}

Spacer.prototype.getOptions = function () {
  return this.options;
}

var spacer = new Spacer().initialize({ name: 'spacer' });

spacer.getOptions(); // { name: 'spacer' }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x6b49f0u/)

Answer (score 2):

```
function spacer() {
  // do stuff
  console.log(spacer.options);
}
spacer.initialize = function(options) { // needed an assignment operator and function keyword
   spacer.options = options;
}
```

To create a method you need to use the function keyword.

To the browser, this

```
spacer.initialize(options) {
  spacer.options = options;
}
```

is interpreted like this

```
spacer.initialize(options); // method evocation
{spacer.options = options;}; // anonymous object
```

Comment: You should include an explanation, however brief, of what you're changing and why. It will make the answer much more helpful.

Comment: I did that. Unfortunately, that did not work. Still same error.

Comment: I was assuming that spacer was a function, and a function is an object. so you should be able to add methods to it.

Answer (score 2):

Change the way it is defined

```
//from
spacer.initialize(options) {
  spacer.options = options;
}

//to
spacer.initialize = function(options) {
  spacer.options = options;
}
```

In your JS remove the **()** from window.resize call

```
spacer.initialize({ id:1 });
window.onresize = spacer;
```

Comment: I did that. Unfortunately, that did not work. Still same error.